# I don't know what operation to preform with "!"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, factorial

I am currently working on my math homework (the book was optional), and I don't know what to do when I see the "!". I am trying to evaluate a problem with this symbol.

Comment: For future reference: [List of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it isn't an exclamation point, $!$ is a factorial. That is for a positive integer $n$

$$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 2 \cdot 1.$$

For instance $5!=5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=120$.

Answer (score 3):

There are several rather common operations associated with $!$. By the far the most common is the **factorial** which is defined for natural numbers as
$$n! = n\times (n-1)!\ \ \ \text{with}\ \ \ 0! = 1$$
This is simply a product of all the natural numbers from $1$ to $n$. Incidentally, this is also the number of ways to rearrange $n$ distinct objects into order.

For your interest, another commonly used and related notation is the **double factorial** $n!!$ This is often used to denote the product of the *odd* numbers from $1$ to $n$.

Yet another one which uses an exclamation mark (although this one is much rarer from my experience) that I have seen is the number of *derangements* or the **subfactorial**. This is sometimes denoted
$!n$ and is given as
$$!n = n\times !(n-1) + (-1)^n\ \ \text{with}\ \ \ !0 = 1$$

Comment: n!=n×(n−1)!   I don't quite understand this. I got the answer 20, when n = 5.

Comment: You have $n! = n \times (n-1)!$ Note the exclamation mark at the end of the $(n-1)$. You are repeatedly applying the definition, it is _not_ $n! = n \times (n-1)$ without the $!$

Comment: It seems recursive. I was a bit intimidated by that.

Comment: Well it _is_ recursively defined. If it helps, we don't really apply the recursive definition in most cases. We simply understand it to be the product of all the integers between $1$ and $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to prove that the number of *different* subsets with $\,k\,$ elements that a set with $\,n\,$ elements , $\,0\leq k\leq n\,$ , is given by what's called **the binomial coefficient$$

$$\binom{n}{k}:\stackrel{\text{Def.}}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

If the above is way too hard, you can try to work out different cases: for any $\,n\,$, the cases $\,k=0,1,2,,n-2,n-1,n\,$ . On purpose I recommend you these ones as you will find something really nice, and sometimes surprising at the beginning, about these cases.
Perhaps first choosing, say $\,n=3,4\,$ , then something more general.

Comment: A $:=$ with Def over it, perhaps the least ambiguous use of notation I've ever seen.

Comment: That's usually less cumbersome and less long than explaining to begining students that := in mathematics means "LHS defined by RHS".